# Solving 2d diffusion (heat) equation with CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, differential-equations

I am learning CUDA with trying to solve some standard problems. As a example, I am solving the diffusion equation in two dimensions with the following code. But my results are different than the standard results and I am not able to figure that out.

```
//kernel definition
__global__ void diffusionSolver(double* A, double * old,int n_x,int n_y)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(i*(n_x-i-1)*j*(n_y-j-1)!=0)
        A[i+n_y*j] = A[i+n_y*j] + (old[i-1+n_y*j]+old[i+1+n_y*j]+
                       old[i+(j-1)*n_y]+old[i+(j+1)*n_y] -4*old[i+n_y*j])/40;


}

int main()
{


    int i,j ,M;
    M = n_y ;
    phi = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
    phi_old = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
    dummy = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
    int iterationMax =10;
    //phase initialization
    for(j=0;j<n_y ;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n_x;i++)
        {
            if((.4*n_x-i)*(.6*n_x-i)<0)
                phi[i+M*j] = -1;
            else 
                phi[i+M*j] = 1;

            phi_old[i+M*j] = phi[i+M*j];
        }
    }

    double *dev_phi;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_phi, n_x*n_y*sizeof(double));

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(100,10);
    dim3 numBlocks(n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.x, n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.y);

    //start iterating 
    for(int z=0; z<iterationMax; z++)
    {
        //copy array on host to device
        cudaMemcpy(dev_phi, phi, n_x*n_y*sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        //call kernel
        diffusionSolver<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_phi, phi_old,n_x,n_y);

        //get updated array back on host
        cudaMemcpy(phi, dev_phi,n_x*n_y*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        //old values will be assigned new values
        for(j=0;j<n_y ;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<n_x;i++)
            {
                phi_old[i+n_y*j] = phi[i+n_y*j];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me if there is anything wrong in this process? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "old values will be assigned new values" section is pointless. You can either perform a device-to-device memcpy and eliminate the transfers and host side loop, or better still, just swap the pointer values.

Comment: @talonmies, thanks for suggestion. I will swap pointer values(that seems easy)

Comment: You haven't said anywhere in that code what the values of n_x and n_y are, and you are performing any error checking at all in your code. Every CUDA API call returns a status. You should be checking them all to make sure the kernel is actually running and code executing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big mistake you have is that phi_old is passed to the kernel and used by the kernel but this is a host pointer.
Malloc a dev_phi_old using cudaMalloc. Set it to default value and copy it to the GPU first time before entering the z loop.

Comment: In addition to mistake you pointed out I had to put extra condition in kernel call (if(i<n_x && j <n_y) do something ...). Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I am wondering why it is necessary to condition if(i<n_x && j <n_y)..!!

Comment: The reason is that you need to filter out the threads which will lead to indexing out of bounds. Sometimes you are not able to launch exactly the amount of threads in X and Y for a given dimension n_x and n_y.

Answer (score 5):

talonmies, brano and huseyin have already pointed out some mistakes of your code.

Diffusion (heat) equation is one of the classical example of partial differential equations solvable with CUDA. There is also a thorough example in Chapter 7 of the CUDA by Example book.

As a reference to future Users, I'm providing below a full worked example including both, CPU and GPU codes. Instead of swapping pointers, as suggested by talonmies, I'm just condensing two Jacobi iterations in a single loop.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#define BLOCK_SIZE_X 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y 16

/***********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU */
/***********************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU(const float * __restrict__ T_old, float * __restrict__ T_new, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

                                //                         N 
    int P = i + j*NX;           // node (i,j)              |
    int N = i + (j+1)*NX;       // node (i,j+1)            |
    int S = i + (j-1)*NX;       // node (i,j-1)     W ---- P ---- E
    int E = (i+1) + j*NX;       // node (i+1,j)            |
    int W = (i-1) + j*NX;       // node (i-1,j)            |
                                //                         S 

    // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
    if (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1) T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_old[E] + T_old[W] + T_old[N] + T_old[S]);
}

/***********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - CPU */
/***********************************/
void Jacobi_Iterator_CPU(float * __restrict T, float * __restrict T_new, const int NX, const int NY, const int MAX_ITER)
{
    for(int iter=0; iter<MAX_ITER; iter=iter+2)
    {
        // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
        for(int j=1; j<NY-1; j++) 
            for(int i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
                float T_E = T[(i+1) + NX*j];
                float T_W = T[(i-1) + NX*j];
                float T_N = T[i + NX*(j+1)];
                float T_S = T[i + NX*(j-1)];
                T_new[i+NX*j] = 0.25*(T_E + T_W + T_N + T_S);
            }

        for(int j=1; j<NY-1; j++) 
            for(int i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
                float T_E = T_new[(i+1) + NX*j];
                float T_W = T_new[(i-1) + NX*j];
                float T_N = T_new[i + NX*(j+1)];
                float T_S = T_new[i + NX*(j-1)];
                T[i+NX*j] = 0.25*(T_E + T_W + T_N + T_S);
            }
    }
}

/******************************/
/* TEMPERATURE INITIALIZATION */
/******************************/
void Initialize(float * __restrict h_T, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    // --- Set left wall to 1
    for(int j=0; j<NY; j++) h_T[j * NX] = 1.0;
}


/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int NX = 256;         // --- Number of discretization points along the x axis
    const int NY = 256;         // --- Number of discretization points along the y axis

    const int MAX_ITER = 1;     // --- Number of Jacobi iterations

    // --- CPU temperature distributions
    float *h_T              = (float *)calloc(NX * NY, sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_old          = (float *)calloc(NX * NY, sizeof(float));
    Initialize(h_T,     NX, NY);
    Initialize(h_T_old, NX, NY);
    float *h_T_GPU_result   = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));

    // --- GPU temperature distribution
    float *d_T;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old,  NX * NY * sizeof(float)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T,     h_T, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old, d_T, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

    // --- Grid size
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_X, BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid (iDivUp(NX, BLOCK_SIZE_X), iDivUp(NY, BLOCK_SIZE_Y));

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the host
    Jacobi_Iterator_CPU(h_T, h_T_old, NX, NY, MAX_ITER);

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T,     d_T_old, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old     starting from data stored in d_T
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old, d_T    , NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T         starting from data stored in d_T_old
    }

    // --- Copy result from device to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_result, d_T, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // --- Calculate percentage root mean square error between host and device results
    float sum = 0., sum_ref = 0.;
    for (int j=0; j<NY; j++)
        for (int i=0; i<NX; i++) {
            sum     = sum     + (h_T_GPU_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_ref = sum_ref + h_T[j * NX + i]                                * h_T[j * NX + i];
        }
    printf("Percentage root mean square error = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum / sum_ref));

    // --- Release host memory 
    free(h_T);
    free(h_T_GPU_result);

    // --- Release device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_T));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_T_old));

    return 0;
}
```

The **Utilities.cu** and **Utilities.cuh** files needed to run such an example are maintained at this [github page](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA-Utilities).

Comment: Is it necessary to have two variables of old and new?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
A[i+n_y*j] = A[i+n_y*j] + (old[i-1+n_y*j]+old[i+1+n_y*j]+old[i+(j-1)*n_y]+old[i+(j+1)*n_y] -4*old[i+n_y*j])/40;
```

You are dividing by 40(integer) which can result in wrong diffusing rate. Actually can result in none-diffusing.

But A is an array of doubles.

Divide the diffuse rate by 40.0 and see if it works.

If this is from Jos-Stam's solver, it should be 4.0 not 40

Theres also another thing:

```
-4*old[i+n_y*j])/40;
```

Here you are multiplying with 4(integer). This can cause a integral-casting too!

This:

```
-4.0*old[i+n_y*j])/40.0;
```

decreases some errors.

Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks for reply tugrul, I tried with 40.0 but results are still different(percentage error ~40). I am using 40.0 instead of 4.0 to ensure it is numerically stable. Can you please take a look at procedure of copying array to host(and vice versa) and see if is the correct way specially this is supposed to be done multiple times.

Comment: As you mentioned my array values are not changing at all..!! I have tried your solution but it not working either. can you suggest any method so that I can ensure that kernel is actually called?

Comment: is size of double same in gpu? Maybe it is 128 bit in gpu and 64 bit in cpu

Comment: can you tell what are the differencies between what you get and what you want?

Comment: what is the magnitude of value in old[i-1+n_y*j] ?

Comment: Thanks a lot tugrul for your efforts. I know that CPU is 64 bit and I have installed 64 bit drivers (also other simple programmes run well). What I am getting is "independant of number of iterations my initial array is not changing". old[i+n_y*j] is in range -1<=old[i+n_y*j]<=1. Again thanks a lot for pointing out these questions as they were useful.

Comment: Ok. Im happy to help. In the mean time, old[] was between 0.001 and 0.999 in a similar program