# Sequential programing in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to realize this simple loop in CUDA.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        {
        x[i, j] = (x0[i, j] + a*(x[i - 1, j] + x[i + 1, j] + x[i, j - 1] + x[i, j + 1])) / c;
        }
    }
```

The problem is: to compute e.g. X[i,j] I need to know new value of X[i-1,j] and X[i,j-1] it is easy if I want to calculate this on CPU (calculations are sequential). But GPU is calculating everything parallel so the results received from CPU and GPU are different. I found some info about Dynamic Parallelism in CUDA and about cudaDeviceSynchronize() and believe it could be useful but anyway still have no idea how to implement this loop in the kernel. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Did you want to implement a filter? If so, your code for CPU is wrong. you should copy source data before you compute it

Comment: Considering you are accessing data that could have been modified by another thread in parallel (seems like you are implementing some kind of filter), the simplest workaround is to read the values from one buffer (say "input") and write your computation to another (so "output").
This is how I do some filters that require neighbour pixels values, like blur or median.

Comment: No it's not a filter, it is the linear equation solver from liquid simulator (by Stam). My goal now is to change his code to GPU-code. But yours suggestions could be correct... So should I copy input data and then... no it's still paralel I guess. I need to make it sequentially like in CPU-version.

Answer (score 1):

comments above are right , even with a pure sequential implementation, you need to copy data. Here could be your kernel (without memory management code or any further details):

```
   __global__ void update(...)
    for(int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; i <= N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
{
    for(int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y; j <= N; j += blockDim.y * gridDim.y)
    {
        output[i,j] = update_func(input, i, j);
    }
}
```

which you can invoke (from host), using

```
update<<<dim3(16, 16), dim3(64, 64)>>>(input, output, width, height);
```

replacing launch bounds by whatever value which suits your hardare

Comment: Regis Portalez thank you, my point was to avoid using of standard for-loops in kernel, but if it is not possible... isn't it slower than CPU-version?

Comment: you can avoid them is your array size is small enough and your thread grid large enough. If you have more rows than threads*blocks, you still need a for loop. 
Considering your code, I'd say it will be much faster on GPU, as long as you don't get the data back to CPU too often. But the best you can do is to run the actual code to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Maybe you should read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994679/solving-2d-diffusion-heat-equation-with-cuda)

Comment: Regis Portalez thank you so much. Sounds reasonable. One more question. Why I need to copy data if I want to receive exactly the same thing like in CPU code (first post)?

Comment: consider the same code in 1d, in which you compute the second derivative of your pressure/heat/whatever scalar field. 

You get (for 2 successive iterations):

x[i] =     x[i-1] + x[i+1] - 2.0*x[i];
x[i+1] = x[i] + x[i+2] - 2.0*x[i+1];

if you write directly in x, the computation of x[i+1] will involve x[i], in which you already wrote something which is not the original value. 

Maybe that is what you want, but from the code and the application domain (PDEs), I guess it's not, and you want to compute a laplacian of some kind

Comment: Thank you once more. So probably there is an error in Stam code. He is using new values of e.g. x[i-1] to calculate x[i]. If it is wrong, then yes you are absolutely right, I need a copy of my data.